# GraphDB - get paths among different types of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph DB (using Neo4J) consisting of 5 types of nodes, e.g. filename, type1, type2, type3 and type4.

```
CREATE (:type1{name:type1_A})
CREATE (:type1{name:type1_B})

CREATE (:type2{name:type2_A})
CREATE (:type2{name:type2_B})

CREATE (:type3{name:type3_A})
CREATE (:type3{name:type3_B})

CREATE (:type4{name:type4_A})
CREATE (:type4{name:type4_B})

CREATE (:filename{name:1A_2A_3A_4A})
CREATE (:filename{name:1A_2A_3A_4A_another})
CREATE (:filename{name:1A_2B_3A_4A})
CREATE (:filename{name:1A_2A_3B_4A})
CREATE (:filename{name:1A_2A_3A_4B})
```

For each filename, I created 4 links (with same relationship name) as follows:

```
MATCH(n:type1 {name:'type1_A'}) MATCH(f:filename {name:'1A_2A_3A_4A}) CREATE (n)-[:linked_to]->(f)" 
MATCH(n:type2 {name:'type2_A'}) MATCH(f:filename {name:'1A_2A_3A_4A}) CREATE (n)-[:linked_to]->(f)" 
MATCH(n:type3 {name:'type3_A'}) MATCH(f:filename {name:'1A_2A_3A_4A}) CREATE (n)-[:linked_to]->(f)" 
MATCH(n:type4 {name:'type4_A'}) MATCH(f:filename {name:'1A_2A_3A_4A}) CREATE (n)-[:linked_to]->(f)"
```

and so on for the other filenames.

Now, for instance, I'd like to get all paths involving ***filename*** nodes linked to **type1_A** AND **type2_A** AND **type3_A** AND **type4_A**. In this case, I except '***1A_2A_3A_4A***' and '***1A_2A_3A_4A_another***' nodes and corresponding paths to ***type1_A***, ***type2_A*** and ***type3_A*** nodes.

Can anyone suggest me the corresponding Cypher query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below and see if gets you what you're looking for.

```
MATCH 
  (f:filename), 
  (t1:type1 {name: "type1_A")-[t1lt:linked_to]->(f), 
  (:type2 {name: "type2_A")-[:linked_to]->(f),
  (:type3 {name: "type3_A")-[:linked_to]->(f),
  (:type4 {name: "type4_A")-[:linked_to]->(f)
RETURN f, t1, t1lt
```

Comment: It returns only filename nodes. I need also type[1-4] nodes and paths

Comment: Then you'll just need to assign variables to those as well and add them to the RETURN statement. I've updated the statement to return the :type1 nodes and relationships